# GitHub git remote add origin git@github.com:username/ProjectName a one time process?

Tags: git, github

if I have two git projects on my machine
with two different ProjectNames

can I manage it with this code in two directories like this

```
/foo1$ git remote add origin git@github.com:username/ProjectName-1
/foo2$ git remote add origin git@github.com:username/ProjectName-2
```

Is it getting stored in the directory or in a git config file in system?

Comment: Is it a typo that you put "origin" twice?  The remote names have to be different for each remote.  Otherwise, the second command just overwrites the first.

Comment: @Randal those commands are in 2 different directories (`foo1` and `foo2`)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The information is stored in each repository (project), in the `.git/config` file.

**Yes** you are doing the right thing by adding the remote to each repository separately.

Answer (score 7):

Sure you can. When you create new repository on GitHub it shows help screen how to checkout new project or how to add GitHub as remote:

```
cd existing_git_repo
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/test.git
git push origin master
```

Remotes are stored only locally, you can always change them.

Answer (score 2):

```
git remote add remote_name remote_location
```

remote_name is usually origin in most examples.  If you have more than one remote then you will use a different name.  For github I usually use "github" instead of origin and have command aliases built around this to make life easier (ie- `git config --global alias.pg=push github master`).  There is also a github ruby gem that provides shortcuts for using github.

remote_location is the url or scp path to the remote repo.  Repos using ssh, including private github repos use scp paths in the form of `user@host:path/to/repo.git`.  Github abstracts this out to `git@github:username/repo.git`. Read only repos use http and are simple urls to the git repo `http://host/path/to/repo.git`.